# How do I check java console log.?

Tags: java, java-console

I am running java application and because of some error it gets closed, I want to check the error in log. How can I reopen java console with that log or is there any other way to check the log of java console.?

Comment: You can start the program from a command promt

Comment: What kind of java application?  A webapp?  An Applet? A commandline app?

Comment: try setting a few breakpoints and starting your application in debugging mode

Answer (score 1):

Try printing something on the console.

Eg:`System.out.println("Program Completed").`

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in try catch block, and print your exception in catch block.